# Empty Sweep Hit Result On Overlap with projectile

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm trying to make a projectile shooting system, but the Sweep Result is empty. I need it to see whether or not the projectile hit the bone 'head' and to see the hit location.

I made sure that I have a sweep collision on the projectile movement and the character movement.

Here is the overlapping event with the server event handling the ProjectileDamage:

https://blueprintue.com/blueprint/v9gzb-uf/

(Scroll up to see the OnComponentBeginOverlap Event)

The actual system works, but the sweep result is empty.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now figured out how to fix my issue.

I just had to set the the object type, from the character, from 'Pawn' to World Dynamic. Now the projectile also has a Hit Result.

Answer (score 1):

## Physics or Projectile Movement

Use `OnComponentHit`, not `OnComponentBeginOverlap`, if using physics or a projectile movement component.

#### [OnComponentHit](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UPrimitiveComponent/OnComponentHit/index.html)

> Event called when a component hits (or is hit by) something solid. This could happen due to things like Character movement, using Set Location with 'sweep' enabled, or physics simulation. For events when objects overlap (e.g. walking into a trigger) see the 'Overlap' event.
>
> For collisions during physics simulation to generate hit events, 'Simulation Generates Hit Events' must be enabled for this component.
>
> When receiving a hit from another object's movement, the directions of 'Hit.Normal' and 'Hit.ImpactNormal' will be adjusted to indicate force from the other object against this object.
>
> NormalImpulse will be filled in for physics-simulating bodies, but will be zero for swept-component blocking collisions.

#### [OnComponentBeginOverlap](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UPrimitiveComponent/OnComponentBeginOverlap/index.html)

> Event called when something starts to overlaps this component, for example a player walking into a trigger. **For events when objects have a blocking collision, for example a player hitting a wall, see 'Hit' events.**

## Projectile Movement

If using [Projectile Movement Component](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/UProjectileMovementComponent/index.html), you can also use `OnProjectileStop` event.

## Verify hit is impacting a skeletal mesh

You'll only get a `Bone Name` in the hit result if you are impacting a skeletal mesh.

## Example Project

To see an example of a physics impact and a projectile movement impact hitting a skeletal mesh and returning a bone name, [see this example project](https://github.com/drichardson/UE4Examples/tree/master/OnHit).

Comment: For some reason, the Hit Event does not fire (Mesh)

Comment: I changed it to Hit: https://blueprintue.com/blueprint/jzk39qek/
I think I did all the collision stuff correctly. BlockAllDynamic on the projectile and the mesh is set to the default mesh settings

Comment: I've updated the answer with more information and also provided you with a link to a project that demonstrates this working in a blueprint only project

Comment: Thanks I have a look at it

Comment: I only get a hit if the mesh is also moving. But if the mesh stands still, the projectile goes through

Comment: Thanks OnProjectileStop did the job. Marked your answer as correct